# jQuery UI Menu Collapse on Blur

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu, menu

I think it's annoying the jQuery UI submenus stay open on a mouseblur event. (See the bottom of http://api.jqueryui.com/menu.)

I've been playing around with how to collapse the menu after an amount of time after a `blur` event, but haven't got a good solution.

- The `menublur` event fires on every menu and menu item blur.
- Creating a custom `blur` event for each submenu is awful.

What else could I do? The jQuery UI menu just seems incomplete and not very thought-out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My strategy would be to create a timer on each `menublur` event that is reset when a `menufocus` event is triggered. If we have a submenu open and we mouse off of the entire menu the last event will be `menublur` so after a predefined amount of time we can collapse the menu.

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var menu = $('#menu');
    menu.menu();

    var blurTimer;
    var blurTimeAbandoned = 200;  // time in ms for when menu is consider no longer in focus

    menu.on('menufocus', function() {
        clearTimeout(blurTimer);
    });

    menu.on('menublur', function(event) {
        blurTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            menu.menu("collapseAll", null, true );
        }, blurTimeAbandoned);
    });
});
```

Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cR4EK/)​

Reference: [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout), [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout)

Comment: That works great! I do have a question, though. How come there is still a delay when the [timer is set to 0](http://jsfiddle.net/cR4EK/1/)?

Comment: On Chrome, it appears there is a slight delay for the time to setup a `setTimeout` and the time to `clearTimeout`. If 0 did work, it would be like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cR4EK/2/) which is really poor UI of course. You probably want 200 or more milliseconds for good user experience.

Comment: Yes, I know. I was just curious. Thank you!

Comment: works like a charm, I would use 600 though for the delay